# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I have two linq queries. I want to use result of one query in another query.

```
var t2s = (from temp3 in _ent.Products                       
           where temp3.Row_Num == 2
           select new { temp3.ProductID });
```

Then I use this var in another query:

```
var _query = (from P1 in _ent.brands
              join temp2 in on 
                  new { Produ_ID = (Int32?)P1.Prod_ID } 
                  equals new { Produ_ID = (Int32?)temp2.ProductID }
             );
```

When I run the first query by itself it gives me the right result. If I run the second one without a `join` it gives me right result, but with a `join` gives me the following error:

> error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Comment: Where's the `t2s` in second query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need a join?  What about this:

```
var t2s = _ent.Products.Where(t => t.Row_Num == 1).Select(t =>t.ProductID);

var _query = _ent.brands.Where(b => t2s.Contains(b.Prod_ID));
```

You may need to change things slightly depending on whether ProductID and/or Prod_ID are nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your queries as follows:

```
var t2s = from temp3 in _ent.Products                       
          where
             temp3.Row_Num == 2
          select temp3.ProductID;

var _query = from P1 in _ent.brands
             join temp2 in t2s on P1.Prod_ID equals temp2 
             select ...
```